# Magento - Getting issue while accessing SOAP api over https

Tags: php, web-services, magento, soap, https

SOAP API is not working on https.

After enabling https on my site, I am getting SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1' failed to load external entity "https://example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1"

I have tried even on fresh Magento version 1.7 and 1.9 but both of them giving the same issue.

This is the sample code that I am using, it is working fine with HTTP URL but it is giving issue with https:

```
`try {
    $cli = new SoapClient('https://www.example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1', ["trace" => 1,"exceptions" => true,]);
    $session = $cli->login('test_test', test12345');
    $result = $cli->call($session, 'sales_order.info', 100026xxx);

    echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
    $cli->endSession($session);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($e);
}
```

This is the actual error that I am facing
`SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1' failed to load external entity "http://example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1"`

Comment: Are you able to share some code or other details? The current URL doesn't even list a WSDL file

Comment: Please don't add code to the comment section, rather edit your question to contain all relevant information. Additionally, what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: You realise, of course, that Magento 1 is obsolete and goes out of all support next year?

Comment: thanks...added on details, do you have any idea on this kind of problem.

Comment: Is it your site running with https? Just want to  confirm. Mostly there isn't any restriction for api using http or https. Some cases site may not be running with SSL. Try the api url in browser and see what is happening.

Comment: The same error is coming when I am hitting the API URL (https/http) in browser